# how to export an xhtml form to xls including p:outputText and p:dataTable?

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

i am creating an online time sheet form which then can be exported when approved as excel to be printed. i used primefaces extension pe:exporter for the data table, but i do not know how to export the p:outputText so that it will also exported together with the data table.

Comment: An outputtext outside the datatable?

Comment: yes,, i have a form where user have to fill in their details first then only fill in the time sheet data table.. i need to export both the details and the data table into xls

Comment: Then you need to customize the exporter as far as I know. See their showcase on hpw to do that orbsownloadvthe source. Or try wrapping both in a panel and try to export that.

Comment: ohh okay will try and see how later. thnx!